Unmatched Route Screen issue with Clerk Authentication- Expo React Native App
I am using Clerk for Oauth authentication in my expo app. When a user clicks for Oauth authentication my app, he is redirected to browser to carry out the further authentication process. But what is weird is that when the user has finished authenticating and is redirected back to the app an Unmatched Route screen appears for a brief moment and then the user gets redirected to the screen that I have setup in the onSelectAuth function.
The function looks like this
  const { startOAuthFlow } = useOAuth({ strategy: "oauth_google" });

  const onSelectAuth = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(`~ login.jsx ~ Calling  startOAuthFlow `);

      const { createdSessionId, signIn, signUp, setActive } =
        await startOAuthFlow();

      console.log(`~ login.jsx ~ Finished authentication `);

      if (createdSessionId) {
        console.log(`~ login.jsx ~ Setting Active `);
        await setActive({ session: createdSessionId });
        console.log(`~ login.jsx createdSessionId: ${createdSessionId} `);
        console.log(`~ login.jsx ~ Going to (tabs) `);

        router.push("(tabs)");
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Did not create a session");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

The screen that I see is shown in the image below

I also tried adding the redirect uri in the Clerk's dashboard but that did not work either

Note: I am developing the app in android using Expo Go app. \
Please help me find a solution to this unmatched route screen.
